# Coinbase to Block Chain Transfer Delay

Tags: blockchain.info, unconfirmed-transactions, coinbase.com

I recently sent a friend of mine around $950 in BTC from Coinbase to his BTC wallet on BlockChain.info.

The transaction is showing up as completed in my account, but he claims he has not received the money yet...

I'm not sure why this issue is occurring. Can someone please help? Obviously, with an amount like $950, I can't just lose that money...

Answer (score 4):

Since there is no dispute about the address, you can check whether the transaction has confirmed on any of the blockchain explorers freely available, such as blockexplorer.com or the aforementioned blockchain.info.

If the transaction shows up as confirmed there, and the receiving address matches the address that he told you, the money has been successfully signed over to his control. That's sufficient to prove that you paid.

If the payment is still not showing up in his wallet, the problem is on his side, and he should either look into what's wrong with his wallet or check in with the customer support to fix his access to his funds.

Answer (score 3):

If it is showing up on Coinbase but not on blockchain, there's only two possibilities.

1. You sent to the wrong address. Check the address you sent to in blockchain.info. It should show up with your $950. This is where your coins are. Maybe you miscopied the address. Make sure that your friend owns the address that you sent to.
2. Malware. There is a virus circulating around that swaps out bitcoin address in the clipboard with a hacker's bitcoin address, so when try to send to an address, it will send to the hacker's address.
3. Your friend is having a problem with his blockchain wallet.

Comment: I spoke with a support member at block chain. They said they can confirm that he has received the payment, but he says it has not appeared in his account yet. I'm really sure it was to the correct address. He sent me a screenshot showing his recent transactions, and mine did not show up there...although when the support member showed me his history, it showed the +950 that he received. Is it possible that it delays him receiving it, since it's a bigger amount?

Comment: Not possible that it was delayed, especially if blockchain support can see it. Get your friend to install an SPV wallet like Electrum and import his private key from the Import/Export page.

Comment: I'm not sure how to resolve this...I can see the transaction on his Block Chain history, but the transaction doesn't show in his recent history yet. He claims he still hasn't received it. I'm stuck because at this point I sent $950 that is currently at an idle stage right now..

Comment: He might be pulling your leg. Another question, how did blockchain support know he received it? They don't know anything about him. Did you give them only the address they sent to? Because obviously you sent the coins, but I still think he's either joking with you or you sent it to an address that wasnt his.

Comment: I told them the address I sent to, and they sent me a link with a history of his account deposits and withdrawals. I easily pointed out my transaction to him. He still says he has not received it. I think he's attempting to scams me, but so many say he's legit..

Comment: It's definitely his address. When i

Comment: Go to his account history, all of the transactions match up with those on the screenshot be sent me..

Comment: Then it's not your fault. Either he mistyped his wallet address, or his wallet is really, really broken. Never seen this on blockchain before. As I said, get him to try import his BIP58 seed into Electrum and see if the coins are there.

Comment: So in that screenshot he sent you, you can see the transaction that you made?