# Coinbase to Blockchain Transaction

Tags: transactions, blockchain, unconfirmed-transactions, coinbase.com

**Hello everyone!**

- Recently i received a cryptocurrency to my ***Blockchain Wallet.***

The *Bitcoin* was sent from ***Coinbase*** to my address - I waited for about an **hour.**
And i don't see the transaction and the funds are not updating.

What could be the problem?
I know, that ***Coinbase*** has some delay, before authorizing the transaction.

- Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coinbase to Block Chain Transfer Delay](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/48626/coinbase-to-block-chain-transfer-delay)

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up your wallet yourself? Blockchain wallet's are often used by scammers, because it's easy to set up watch-only wallets where you are actually seeing funds controlled by someone else. If you did not set up your wallet yourself, you should check whether this is the case.

Otherwise, check on a block explorer whether the transaction went to the address you expected and has actually been confirmed. If it's just not showing up on your blockchain wallet, you may want to find some support articles on "How to rescan".

Comment: I've sent the default wallet address, which is "bitcoinwallet".

The one, automatically generated by Blockchain upon the creation of the account.

I've examined my address in Explorer, but i can't see anything in there - transaction, nor the funds are updating.

[EDIT: What other company do you recommend for any future use, if i switch to something else in the future?]

Comment: If the funds have actually not been sent, it sounds like the problem is on Coinbase's end and you should contact their customer support.